# phpMyAdmin no longer automatically logging in

Tags: phpmyadmin, cpanel, geoip

I'm not sure if this is what caused it to stop logging in automatically, but the last thing I did was install the GeoIP library and install/compiled it with "pecl install geoip".

phpMyAdmin resides in /usr/local/cpanel/base/3rdparty/phpMyAdmin/ on my CentOS release 5.8 (Final) server.

Here is the contents of my config.inc.php. I edited my blowfish_secret and also took out most of the code that was commented out:

```
<?php

$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'; /* YOU MUST FILL IN THIS FOR COOKIE AUTH! */

/*
 * Servers configuration
 */
$i = 0;

/*
 * First server
 */
$i++;
/* Authentication type */
//cpanel:$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cpanel';

/* Server parameters */
//cpanel:$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
/* Select mysql if your server does not have mysqli */
// cPanel case 56677
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysql';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;

/*
 * phpMyAdmin configuration storage settings.
 */
// cPanel case 5760
$cfg['UserprefsDisallow'] = array(
    'ShowCreateDb',
    'SuggestDBName',
    'Export/quick_export_onserver',
    'Export/quick_export_onserver_overwrite',
    'Export/onserver',
    'Export/onserver_overwrite',
);

/*
 * End of servers configuration
 */

/*
 * Directories for saving/loading files from server
 */
$cfg['UploadDir'] = '';
$cfg['SaveDir'] = '';

// cpanel: cases 36079, 36080, 36144
$cfg['ShowChgPassword'] = false;
$cfg['ShowCreateDb'] = false;
$cfg['SuggestDBName'] = false;
$cfg['AllowUserDropDatabase'] = false;

?>
```

I've read that changing the cPanel password and syncing it to the mysql database would solve this issue but it worked fine all along with different passwords on each and I would prefer to keep it that way for security reasons.

Anyone have any idea why this happened and/or how to get back the auto-login functionality from withing cPanel?

Comment: I should also note that there is no /etc/php.d directory for some reason. Could php.d be located elsewhere?

Comment: More info that might be related to the original issue. When I restore a database through cPanel the process looks like it completed successfully but the database never actually gets updated. I have to use phpMyAdmin or MySQL to restore databases. I did a forced update of cPanel through WHM in hopes that it would fix the problem but no dice. Would moving up from release to current make any difference at this point?

I also just noticed that I installed the apache GeoIP AND the pecl version. Would that cause any problems? I should have done more research before jumping the gun I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that when you modified the blowfish cookie secret you broke the authicaticion connectivity between cPAnel/WHM and PhpMyAdmin.  If you have a backup of the configuration file, I recommend restoring that.  Otherwise you can resolve this issue by reinstalling PhpMyAdmin with the following commands.

Backup current PhpMyAdmin

```
mv -v  /usr/local/cpanel/base/3rdparty/phpMyAdmin{,.backup.`date +%F.%T`}
```

Reinstall PhpMyAdmin

```
/usr/local/cpanel/bin/updatephpmyadmin --force
```